# propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer and environment variable

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to load a property file from an environment variable, so here's what I tried:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>

                <value>classpath:messages/application.properties</value>
                <value>file:${My_ENV_VAR}/*.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />

    </bean>
```

I have a new environment variable named `My_ENV_VAR=C:\Program Files\My Folder\props.properties`
but when stopping and starting the application the value of the variable is not set, any ideas why?

**UPDATE**: Requirement

I want to read the hibernate properties (url,username,password) in the **applicationContext.xml** from an external property file on file system, which its path is stored in an environment variable.

Comment: See Bozho's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Comment: How do you know it is not set? Also you should pass file/file pattern like `file:${My_ENV_VAR}/*.properties` not a directory.

Comment: sorry i updated the post, i know it's not set because after build i see the applicationContext and i can see that the value `<value>file:${My_ENV_VAR}</value>` is not changed.

Comment: It won't be substituted during build, spring will do it in runtime. If you want it to be substituted in build time, configure maven filtering or equivalent.

Comment: how to configure maven to do that please ?

Comment: Here is link: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to create the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. That's a chicken / egg problem, it can't work!

Try expression language instead (see [this section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based) for reference), but in your case it's tricky because you want to mix static and dynamic content. Probably something like this will work:

```
<property name="locations"
  value="classpath:messages/application.properties,
  #{ T(java.lang.System).getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')}" />
  <!-- changed method name, it's getenv(), not getEnv() -->
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand, i want the property placeholder to point to a property file it's value is read from an environment variable, such thing is not doable ?

Comment: i added an update for the requirement if there's another solution for what i am trying to do.

Comment: @fresh_dev the thing is: you are using the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer syntax while you are creating it.

Comment: it doesn't work, what do i need to get spring expression language to work beside it's jar ? do i need to add anything in `beans xmlns` declaration?

Comment: @fresh_dev uhm, what Spring version are you using? In 3.x it should work out of the box...

Comment: i am using version 3.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: but BTW, will the value be replaced during runtime not build time ? and how to check that the value is replaced if it's replaced during runtime ?

Comment: i am getting an exception now in runtime: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 20): Method call: Method getEnv(java.lang.String) cannot be found on java.lang.System type`

Comment: what do you think about this exception ?

Comment: @fresh_dev my bad, it's System.getenv()

Comment: well this exception is gone, but application cannot start yet, i am getting ClassNotFoundException for a class that's already in the target ! so how to make sure that this code works fine since it's getting applied during runtime then ?

Comment: @fresh_dev post your stack trace in a new question

Answer (score 1):

Yo should be use of this manner:

First declare the spring bean

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>             
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory create the file `config.properties` and put this:

```
jboss.variable=${jboss.modules.dir}
```

Note: When I deploy JBoss 6 EAP the log shows me:

```
jboss.modules.dir = C:\Java\jee-container\jboss-eap-6.1\modules
```

and use the variable in application context file:

```
<bean id="nameOfBean"
    class="com.moeandjava.pusku.MySpringBean">
    <property name="path" value="${jboss.variable}" />
</bean>
```

Sorry for my bad english