# Java Spring: How to use `@Value` annotation to inject an `Environment` property?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Using a construct such as

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    private String key;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        key = env.getProperty("SOME_KEY_PROPERTY");

    }

    ....
}
```

it is possible to assign some field with some property.

Is there a shorter, more concise form to do this?

Comment: look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("#{environment.SOME_KEY_PROPERTY}")
    private String key;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 53):

You should be able to do this(assuming that you have a PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer registered)

```java
    @Value("${SOME_KEY_PROPERTY}")
    private String key;
```

*Note* you can set a default value with:

```java
    @Value("${SOME_KEY_PROPERTY:default-value}")
```

Comment: Note, this is for Spring 3.1+ only.

Comment: This worked for me in my Spring Boot app (running spring-core 4.2.5.RELEASE), and it appears much cleaner than the other accepted answer.

Comment: Ok but how do I configure said PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer to grab the environment variables values?

Comment: you can use this approach on a setter method, too

Comment: @ach if I understand correctly, the difference between 3.1+ and lower is the `$` vs `#`. is that right?

Comment: @asgs The `#` tells spring that inside it is a SpEL expression and one expression you have is `environment` to get values from the environment. On the other hand, `$` express a property that spring will try to load its value, from a property file, environment, command-line arguments, etc.

Comment: @PhoneixS if `$` can handle environment variables, then I guess, there's no need to use `#` (at least from a consistency perspective)

Comment: @asgs you're correct for environment variables. But `#` can handle more things, so maybe some projects have more `#` than `$`.

Comment: what other property can you lookup other than `environment` using `#`?

Answer (score 32):

You might also find it useful to provide a ***default value*** in case the variable is not defined:

```
@Value("${some_property:default_value}")
private String key;
```

Otherwise you'll get an exception whenever `some_property` is not defined.

`default_value` can also be blank, in that case it will behave as if `some_property` was optional:

```
@Value("${some_property:}")
private String key;
```

(Notice the colon)

If the default value contains special characters (dot, colon, etc.), then wrap it in SpEL like this:

```
@Value("${some_property:#{'default_value'}}")
private String key;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need to add an environment variable as default value.

```
@Value("${awsId:#{environment.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}")
@Value("${awsSecret:#{environment.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}")
```

This is a combination of two previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

There are 17 ways to override a property value in spring boot, one of them is environment variables (Item 10. in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

The only trick is that you have to convert property names to to uppercase and underscore. For example if you want to overwrite the property

`myApp.myProperty`

then you have to have an environment variable called

`MYAPP_MYPROPERTY`

this means that you can just have

@Value("${myApp.myProperty}")

without any customization and you can still overwrite it with an environment variable