# Inject system environment variable into Spring Annotation with placeholder

Tags: java, spring

I know you can inject environment variables with the `@Value` annotation like this

```
    @Value("#{systemEnvironment['AWS_ENV']}")
    private String envTarget;
```

If I am using a Spring annotation however can I inject the environment variable in-line into the String value? For example something like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:secrets-${#{systemEnvironment['AWS_ENV']}.properties")
```

Obviously the above doesn't work as it tries to resolve `systemEnvironment['AWS_ENV']` as a jvm property. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: See Spring profiles, or have a single aws.properties file and move the placeholder to inside the properties file.

Comment: can you reference system environment variables from within a properties file? I'm not sure that will even work because I'm using the PropertySource annotation to load the property file in the first place

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Spring: How to use `@Value` annotation to inject an `Environment` property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617181/java-spring-how-to-use-value-annotation-to-inject-an-environment-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeholder could be moved to a single aws.properties file:

```
aws.properties 
envTarget = ${AWS_ENV}
```

then:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:aws.properties")
```

For local development, the placeholder can be added as JVM parameters in the run configuration, but that can become a pain to manage.  An alternative would be to have a aws-local.properties (located in same resources folder), but this file is in .gitignore so secrets are never committed.  Then there is a single JVM parameter to use the local [profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles).

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer did partially solve my problem I ended up just manually configuring the Properties without using the PropertySource annotation. This allowed me to have better control over the bean lifecycles and the property file to load.

[Spring Environment Property Source Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416005/spring-environment-property-source-configuration)