# Default and user-supplied property files w/ Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, properties-file

I'd like to allow my Spring 3.1.2 application to load configuration properties from a default properties file embedded within my jar and additionally allow the user to specify the path to an overriding properties file as a command line parameter.

I understand I can use `<context:property-placeholder>` for the simple scenario of loading the properties from my class path, but how might I handle the scenario above with properties from potentially two merged property files?

The scenario I'm trying to duplicate is basically that addressed by the `CompositeConfiguration` of Apache Commons Configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add properties file name via system properties

Check this

[how to read System environment variable in Spring applicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext)

http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html

**UPD**

1 . The first way to go is to declare PSPC as

```
      <context:property-placeholder 
         location="classpath:app.properties, classpath:user.properties"
         ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Then you include your app.properties into jar.

User includes (or not) a folder containing user.properties into the classpath.

user.properties takes precedence over app.properties.

2 . If you need user to specify the exact file

```
    <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:app.properties, file:${userPropsPath}"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

User adds `-DuserPropsPath="<full path here>"`

---

Both cases are working and tested with spring-3.1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one important element is missing- how can the two property files (one supplied as an argument to the app, the other with default values in a resource) be merged or treated as a composite?  The scenario I'm trying to duplicate is basically that addressed by the `CompositeConfiguration` of Apache Commons Configuration.

Comment: I wasn't working over the weekend, so this was my first opportunity to review your most excellent answer.  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!