# Getting the present working directory using spring

Tags: java, spring

This is the code to get the present working directory of a java application at runtime.

```
String currentWorkingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Is there any way by which this can be configured using the spring-context xml.

For ex:

```
<bean id="csvReportGenerator" class="some.path.CSVReportGenerator">  
<constructor-arg name="outputFileName" value="${currentWorkingDirectory}/${reportOutputFileGeneric}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using Spring expressions. See section 6.4.1 of [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) article

```
<property name="userDir" value="#{ systemProperties['user.dir'] }"/>
<property name="fileSep" value="#{ systemProperties['file.separator'] }"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `classpath:` or can use `./` if you are deploying in an unix environment(which usually is). Say, `classpath:sample.properties` or `./sample.properties`

Answer (score 1):

In `spring-context.xml` You can use

1) `classpath:filename.properties` or

2) `./filename.properties`

3) `file:./`

For current dir of `context-xml`, `./` should work, but for working dir, `file:./` works fine.

eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="properties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="singleton" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/shaharma.properties</value>
                <value>./shaharma-custom.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```