# NumberFormatException when injecting int property

Tags: spring, setter, numberformatexception

This is my class :

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer pph = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
pph.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("one.properties"), new ClassPathResource("two.properties")});
context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(pph);
context.refresh();

Controller obj1 = (Controller) context.getBean("controller");
System.out.println(obj1.getMessage());

Controller2 obj2 = (Controller2) context.getBean("controller2");
System.out.println(obj2.getMessage());
System.out.println(obj2.getInteger());
```

This is the relevant xml configuration:

```
   <bean id="controller" class="com.sample.controller.Controller">
       <property name="message" value="${ONE_MESSAGE}"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="controller2" class="com.sample.controller.Controller2">
       <property name="message" value="${TWO_MESSAGE}"/>
        <property name="integer" value="${TWO_INTEGER}"/>
   </bean>
```

one.properties:

```
ONE_MESSAGE=ONE
```

two.properties:

```
TWO_MESSAGE=TWO
TWO_INTEGER=30
```

TWO_MESSAGE is assigned correctly as String TWO. 
I am getting NumberFormatException when injecting a TWO_INTEGER. 
Is there a way to achieve this without adding a setter that takes String and coverts it to int in Controller2 class?

The error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller2' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${TWO_INTEGER}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is obviously not finding the properties files or the properties files do not contain any property like `${TWO_INTEGER}`. Have you check this?

Comment: I checked this. In fact, other String properties from the same file are getting assigned correctly. one.properties has : `ONE_MESSAGE=ONE` and two.properties has : `TWO_MESSAGE=TWO
TWO_INTEGER=30` and 'TWO_MESSAGE' property is read correctly. Just, to clarify. there are two lines in two.properties not the way its formatted here to show one line.Thanks.

Comment: You could edit your question and add this relevant information. It will be better formatted as in a comment.

Comment: Why you can't define PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in xml file?

Comment: LaurentG : edited the question.                                                             @bellabax : The properties file names are decided at run time. Unless there is a way to define it in xml file and then change it programatically, I have to do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: you can pass runtime names in command line as system properties with -D option or like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your application falling in this line (please provide full stacketrace if i mistake):

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

because Spring can't parse `${TWO_INTEGER}` (this properties doesn't loaded in context as yet). So you can just move context initializing after properties loaded:

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
 PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer pph = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
 pph.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("one.properties"), new ClassPathResource("two.properties")});
 context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(pph);
 context.setConfigLocation("beans.xml");
 context.refresh();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot for the solution and the explanation. Really appreciate it. Curious : Why are the String properties read correctly even when they are in the same file?