# Load a properties file from a path specified in environment variable in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hello I am new to Spring so please forgive me if its a silly question.

I need to load a properties file from a path specified in the environment variables, For example, my environment variable will contain a pah to a folder - MY_ENV=D:\abc. And in this directory i will have my .properties file.

Thanks

Comment: Look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose the property in ${}:

```
<ctx:property-placeholder location="file:${MY_ENV}/yourfile.properties"/>
```

Comment: I am getting a FileNotFoundException. But if i hardcode (D:\abc) the path i get the output

Comment: what if you declare your env property like this: MY_ENV=d:/abc  i.e. : / instead of \

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpEL to load environment variables into your configs:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="com.mypackage.SomeClass">
    <property name="somePropertiesPath" value="#{environment['MY_ENV']}/my.properties" />
</bean>
```

I don't know if you were looking to use your properties as a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or just as another `Properties` bean, so if you clarify that point, I can give you the exact xml you need.