# Spring to read from my system environment variables

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I want to use my system environment variables (i.e use variable `FOO` that I have defined in my `.bash_profile` `export FOO=BAR`) for values in Spring's applicationContext.xml;

For example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" ...>
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${FOO}" />
...
</bean>
```

I use both the Maven-tomcat-plugin and Tomcat inside IntelliJ to run my server.

Right now when my webapp starts up, it can't find the system variables.

What do I have to do to get Spring to read from my system environment variables?

P.S. I have already checked out [how to read System environment variable in Spring applicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext), but doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 2):

System environment variables are different to the JVM system properties - which the spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` gives you access to. So you'd need to add to the JVM command:

```
java ... -DFOO=${FOO}
```

(where `-DFOO` is defining "FOO" as a JVM system property and `${FOO}` is inserting the "BAR" value from your "FOO" environment variable)

See also the [ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) - with the `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE` property and a few other options.

Answer (score 1):

try this (Spring Expression Language)

```
<bean id="dataSource" ...>
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{systemEnvironment.FOO}" />
...
</bean>
```

or add this line

```
<context:property-placeholder/>
```

to application context