# How populate util:properties in spel

Tags: java, spring

In Spring's configuration xml with SpEL we can populate the list in this way:

```
<util:list id="cities">
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Chicago" p:state="IL" p:population="2853114"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Atlanta" p:state="GA" p:population="537958"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Dallas" p:state="TX" p:population="1279910"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Houston" p:state="TX" p:population="2242193"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Odessa" p:state="TX" p:population="90943"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="El Paso" p:state="TX" p:population="613190"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Jal" p:state="NM" p:population="1996"/>
<bean class="com.habuma.spel.cities.City"
p:name="Las Cruces" p:state="NM" p:population="91865"/>
</util:list>
```

how we can populate util:properties by Strings??

```
<util:properties id="some">

....

</util:properties>
```

Comment: There is no SpEL here... So not sure why you think that.

Comment: is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `props` element, like this:

```
<props>
    <prop key="key1">value1</prop>
    <prop key="key2">value2</prop>
    ...
</props>
```

But that is not SpEL, as @M. Deinum already pointed out.

EDIT: incorporating some of the comments in the answer:

`<util:properties>` loads a Properties instance from the resource location specified by the "location" attribute, something like `<util:properties id="some" location="myfile.properties" />`. The following post shows how to read the location from a system property: [how to read System environment variable in Spring applicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext)

Comment: <util:properties> loads a Properties instance from the resource location specified by the "location" attribute, something like <util:properties id="some" location="myfile.properties" />

Comment: but what if i want read systemProperty -DAPP.LOG_PATH=/Users/wsaryada/tmp into util:properties ?

Comment: you mean something like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext. See the response from "amra".