# Spring: Accessing environment variables inside applicationConfig.xml

Tags: spring

I would like to set my db credentials and other secret values as part of environment variables. Is there a way of accessing the environment variables inside applicationConfig.xml

I tried `<property name="username" value="#{systemEnvironment['db_username']}" />`. However this did not work. Am I missing something?

Many were telling me how to access values from a properties file. I need to access the environment variable directly.

My code is as follows:-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.dhana.*" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="xxxx" />
        <property name="username" value="${db_username}" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: No any error message?

Comment: No, but as I access the service it shows org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException. However when I hard code it back, it lets me connect to DB.

Comment: check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have to set **searchSystemEnvironment** value to make it work.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"   
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Then, we should able to access ${MY_ENV_VAR}.

Comment: Getting the following exception:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'db_username' in string value "${db_username}"
 at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
 at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
 at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)

Comment: Spring which version?

Comment: 4.x version of Spring.

Comment: Please refer to edited code. You see something wrong. Please take the fact into consideration that I am not using any properties file. I want to access the environment variable directly.

Comment: Try adding <context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

Comment: Rakesh the issue is resolved. You don't need the one mentioned as part of your last comment. The problem is Eclipse did not recognize the Environment variables unless it is restarted. I am using Eclipse Mars version. The moment I restarted Eclipse it worked well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables using ${}
For example if you want to add a config file which location depends on a environment variable named 'env_config_path' you can use this:

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="file:${env_config_path}/configuration.properties" />
```

I do not recomend you to use environment variables for concrete values, i think it's a better aproach to use a file pointed by a environment variable, as in my example.

You can force the environment variable value when loading your java program using a paremeter like the following:

```
-Denv_resource_path="/Users/mylogin/work/myproject/development_environment_resources"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would rather want to use "systemProperties", like so -

```
value="#{systemProperties['db_username']}"
```

Comment: Also check the following thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a Property file(xxxx.properties) and put all your environment related information in your property file and place it in classpath.

for ex: put your environment values something like below

```
    jdbc.userName = xxx
    jdbc.password = yyy
```

2. In your xml file. add the below code

   ```
   <bean id = "prop"
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
       <value>classpath*:xxxx.properties</value>
   </property>
   ```
3. Now you can call the environment variable from your propertry file as below

   ```
   <bean id="dataSource" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="${}"/>
     <property name="url" value="${}"/>
     <property name="username" value="${jdbc.userName}"/>
     <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>      </bean>
   ```

Just give the property key field inside the value

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

near the start of the XML file.

Also, if you are working in Eclipse, you will need to restart it in order to pick up any account-level environment variable changes.

Answer (score -3):

You can extends the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class and use the env or properties variable within your properties values, using the prefix values ${_var:MY_ENV_OR_PROPERTY}

Optional: Use the -Denv=-dev to create others configs, for example: jdbc-dev.properties.

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://${_var:MARIADB_SERVICE_HOST}:${_var:MARIADB_SERVICE_PORT}/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
jdbc.username=root
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jdbc-properties" class="com.naskar.spring.VariablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc#{systemProperties['env']}.properties"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

VariablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java

```
class VariablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static String resolveValueWithEnvVars(String value) {
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\$\\{_var:(\\w+)\\}|\\$(\\w+)');
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while (m.find()) {
            String envVarName = null == m.group(1) ? m.group(2) : m.group(1);
            String envVarValue = System.getProperty(envVarName);
            if(envVarValue == null) {
                envVarValue = System.getenv(envVarName);
            }
            m.appendReplacement(sb, null == envVarValue ? "" : Matcher.quoteReplacement(envVarValue));
        }

        m.appendTail(sb);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        return resolveValueWithEnvVars(originalValue);
    }

}
```