# context:property-placeholder comma-separated list of resources don't work with system property placeholder

Tags: spring

I can't entirely configure property-placeholder from system property because I can't give comma-separated list of resources.
I'm trying to do like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${config-location}" />
```

I use system property to configure this. It works if I give one location only, like "`classpath:main.properties`", but it does not if I'm trying this: "`classpath:main1.properties,classpath:main2.properties`".
If I use this latter exact value directly in xml configuration it works fine. I guess it resolves comma-separation earlier than placeholders. It should be the other way around.

P.S : version **4.3.4**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible worth tryout would be,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{systemProperties['config-location']}" />
```

[how to read System environment variable in Spring applicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext)

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot