# Use property within application from command line (java -cp) while running jar

Tags: java, spring, command-line, properties, classpath

I am running standalone jar with below command,

```
java -cp my-jar.jar my.com.Main -Dmy.prop=test1
```

Now, I am trying to resolve `my.prop` from my spring config like below,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="my.second.property">${my.prop}-something</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it's not working, is there any way to use `my.prop` within application? Please note, I don't want to use any property file for `my.prop` property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with systemProperties? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution, it seems I was trying with wrong command, working with below command

`java -Dmy.prop=test1 -cp my-jar.jar my.com.Main`