# Read system properties in Spring XML config application with expression language

Tags: java, spring, xml-configuration

It seems to be easy, but it does not work.
I can't paste system property in my easy example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:client.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="client" class="com.epam.spring.Client"
          c:id="${id}"
          p:fullName="#{systemEnvironment['user.name']}"
          p:greeting="${greeting}"
    />
```

Bean Client is ok, but field fullName is always null.
In every case i have in fullName NULL, help me, please, what's wrong?
I tried to use other systemEnvironment['something.else'], but it does not help.
Tries like this:
`p:fullName="#{ T(java.lang.System).getenv().get('java.version') }"`
But id don't want to work.

Comment: Just a clarification: Please, note that in Java context "system properties" are set with `-Dprop=value` and are distinct from OS environment variables. Using SpEL and `systemEnvironment` accesses the latter, not "system properties" mentioned in the title. System properties are accessed by `systemProperties`, example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630883/658826

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! Issue in this line:
`p:fullName="#{systemEnvironment['user.name']}"`

Just write

`p:fullName="#{systemProperties['user.name']}`

and all is ok )))

And it is important, I think, operational system: windows 10