# How to extract the url from application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have this `application.properties`:

```properties
url.up=${url:http://localhost:8080/upload}
```

And I want to extract the url `"http://localhost:8080/upload"`. How can I extract it?

I tried something like this, but the url is null:

```java
String url = config.getPropertyValue("url");
```

Where `getPropertyValue`:

```java
public String getPropertyValue(String propertyKey) {
    return properties.getProperty(propertyKey);
}
```

Comment: You can use *@Value* or *appContext* : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29744955/21233858

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@Value` annotation. For example:

```
@Value("${url}")
private String url;
```

The url variable holds `http://localhost:8080/upload`.

Comment: I just get null and this error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Comment: See my [Minimal @Value test in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75524099).

Answer (score 1):

U can use **@Value** in your class
in your property file U can define

```
url.up=http://localhost:8080/upload
```

In Your class

```
@Value("${url.up}")
private String url;
```

then U can access the value using variable url

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know what class the `config` object is instatiated from which makes it hard to understand what the `properties.getProperty()` method call is doing. Therefore, I'll give you a a more general answer. As you are using Spring, you basically have two very elegant solutions to retrieve data from your application property files. If you just need a single value (as in your example the `url.up` field), then you would typically directly *inject* that value into the class that needs this data as in the following short Kotlin snippet (in java this would be very similar, just look up the `@Value` annotation on the internet).

```
@Component
class PropertyPrinter(
    @Value("\${url.up}") private val url: String
) {
    @PostConstruct
    fun postConstruct() {
        println("URL is: $url")
    }
}
```

The other way would be to create a dedicated config class that hold a bunch logically connected fields and add the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) for a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Value` or `appContext`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29744955/21233858

Comment: I get null and this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute if I use: ` @Value("${url}")
    String API;`

Comment: your variable is named "url.up" not "url". becarefull of that. and the text after = is your value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).