# Minimal @Value test in Spring

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

I'm new to `Spring` and struggling with its complexity and opaque documentation.
My question is **How does one write a minimal @Value test?**

Consider this test module, in `MinimalValueTest.java`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@Component
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MinimalValueTest {

    @Value("${test.property}")
    public static String testProperty;

    @Test
    public void test() {
      if (testProperty == null) {
        System.out.println("*** FAILED ***");
      } else {
        System.out.println("*** SUCCEEDED ***");
      }
      // Unit tests will go here
    }
}
```

This test references this property defined in the `src/test/resources/application.properties` file:

```
test.property=a_test_property
```

Running this outputs `*** FAILED ***`.

Extra credit: which Spring documentation best explains how to do this?

Comment: Make the testProperty non static, then it works. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field and also what Sergey says below, annotate the test with @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

/**
 * This simple example uses an @Value annotation.
 */
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MinimalValueTest {

    @Value("${test.property}")
    String testProperty;

    @Test
    public void test() {
      Assertions.assertTrue(testProperty != null);
      Assertions.assertEquals("a_test_property", testProperty);
    }
}
```